# WebSocket from Dart/Flutter to Python/Flask

Tags: python, dart, flask, websocket

I am trying to set up bidirectional communication between my Flutter android project and a server written in Python/Flask.

The code on the python side is basically the same as can be found at https://flask-sock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html. ie.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sock import Sock

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)


@sock.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    while True:
        data = ws.receive()
        ws.send(data)
```

On the Dart side, I have:

```
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
  Uri.parse('wss://10.0.2.2:5000/echo'),
);
```

And the dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` file is:

```
web_socket_channel: ^2.1.0
```

Running it I get the bizarre error message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2022 17:49:09] code 400, message Bad request version ('\x18±-8ÛF\x18Ã\x9b(ôP')
```

There is nothing wrong with the flask side of things, my app processes the standard html requests fine. But setting up the websockets causes these runtime complaints.

I tried `flask.socketio` and got the similar errors.

Comment: Are you sure the flask server are using encryption? Try connect to: `ws://10.0.2.2:5000/echo` instead for using WebSocket without TLS.

Comment: I tried that and go a 404 error:

`"GET /echo HTTP/1.1" 404`